# Examples of Dulcimer in Electronic Music

Tags: electronic-music

I am looking for examples of rhythmic and flowing dulcimer in electronic songs (ideally of the [Indietronica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternative_dance#Indietronica) sub-variety, but trance or some other form of electronic music would be good). [here is an amateur example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qkF099Hs3FM)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Laariaji, as on

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_hes0hRY9v8

He's recorded a whole bunch of new age/ambient albums, some with Brian Eno...

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of Psytrance music that uses a lead plucked sound that is a layering of a dulcimer and an oud. When the more metallic plucking comes in, that's where the dulcimer comes in.

http://ocremix.org/remix/OCR02028

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this qualifies, but there's a [**santur**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Santur) (an Iranian hammered dulcimer) in Jeff Wayne's [***The War Of The Worlds***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeff_Wayne%27s_Musical_Version_of_The_War_of_the_Worlds): it plays the ‘Fatman’ theme representing the Martians themselves, and can first be heard in the second track, ‘Horsell Common And The Heat Ray’, from about [1:57](https://youtu.be/PjX8lAuRFbc?t=116).